# 3d shapes in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I am drawing three circles in my flex application, using actionscript. But these circles are now pure 2D images, which is not looking good. How can I make it look like 3D using some shadows or shades inside the shape.

Cheers,PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want some 3D-ish effects, you should look into the usage of the bevelFilter. I have found some links that show you how you can use this filter:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3filters/

http://wonderfl.net/c/6AxW

http://www.flashactionscripttutorials.com/?p=projects&actionscript-functie=applyFilter

If you want genuine 3D-objects, you should use a 3D-library (I would recommend Away3D).

Comment: +1 for Array3d. When FlashPlayer 11 is released, it will be able to do hardware rendering using DirectX or OpenGL and drawing a sphere in Away3d is super easy!

Comment: Thanks Michiel, exactly what i was looking for. Hail!